# How to avoid `"msg" is missing` error using sendmail in R?

Tags: r, sendmailr

When I try to use `sendmail` from the `sendmailR` package in R, I am getting this error:

```
Error in .smtp_submit_mail(server, port, headers, msg, verbose) : argument "msg" is missing, with no default
```

Here is the code I am trying to execute:

```
library(sendmailR)
from <- "<some.address@gmail.com>"
to <- "<some.address@gmail.com>"
subject <- "this subject"
body <- "this text right here"
mailControl <- list(smtpServer = "ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM")
sendmail(from = from, to = to, subject = subject,
                  body = body, control = mailControl)
```

This is essentially the same code that can be found in online tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter for the body of the email is called `msg`, not `body`. Use

```
sendmail(from = from, to = to, subject = subject,
                  msg = body, control = mailControl)
```